# BT.601/T.871: Conversion to and from RGB (16bits)

Tags: colors, rgb, color-space

I am trying to make sense of T.871 for conversion in between RGB & YCbCr for 16bits inputs. The equations are trivial to read for 8bits signal. If we check T.871 Section §7, page 4 we get:

> ```
> Y  = Min( Max( 0, Round( 255 * E'Y ) ), 255 )
> Cb = Min( Max( 0, Round( 255 * E'Cb + 128 ) ), 255 )
> Cb = Min( Max( 0, Round( 255 * E'Cr + 128 ) ), 255 )
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> Y  = Min(Max( 0, Round(   0.299 * R + 0.587 * G + 0.114 * B)), 255 )
> Cb = Min(Max( 0, Round(( -0.299 * R - 0.587 * G + 0.886 * B)/1.772 + 128 )), 255 )
> Cr = Min(Max( 0, Round((  0.701 * R - 0.587 * G - 0.114 * B)/1.402 + 128 )), 255 )
> ```
>
> which, to four decimal position accuracy, can be approximated by:
>
> ```
> Y  = Min(Max( 0, Round(  0.299  * R + 0.587  * G + 0.114  * B)), 255 )
> Cb = Min(Max( 0, Round( -0.1687 * R - 0.3313 * G + 0.5    * B + 128 )), 255 )
> Cr = Min(Max( 0, Round(  0.5    * R - 0.4187 * G - 0.0813 * B + 128 )), 255 )
> ```

I can verify the equation of E'Y, E'Cb & E'Cr in BT.601 section §2.5.1 2.5.1 Construction of luminance[...]:

> ```
> E'Y = 0.299 * E'R + 0.587 * E'G + 0.114 * E'B
> ```

And section §2.5.2 Construction of re-normalized colour-difference signals[...]:

> ```
> E'Cr = ( 0.701 * E'R - 0.587 * E'G - 0.114 * E'B) / 1.402
> E'Cb = (-0.299 * E'R - 0.587 * E'G + 0.886 * E'B) / 1.772
> ```

So my (naive) interpretation for 16bits signal is simply:

```
 Y  = Min(Max( 0, Round(   0.299 * R + 0.587 * G + 0.114 * B)), 65535 )
 Cb = Min(Max( 0, Round(( -0.299 * R - 0.587 * G + 0.886 * B)/1.772 + 32768 )), 65535 )
 Cr = Min(Max( 0, Round((  0.701 * R - 0.587 * G - 0.114 * B)/1.402 + 32768 )), 65535 )
```

I tried a quick C code to verify this, but this seems the above equations are not correct.

So my question is: What are the equations for conversion of RGB 16bits signal to YCbCr ?

References:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr
- https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-T.871
- https://www.itu.int/rec/R-REC-BT.601

---

Update: I wrote:

> I tried a quick C code to verify this, but this seems the above
>   equations are not correct.

In order to test the conversion I encapsulated the generated bitstream inside a DICOM file (using gdcmimg) and then converted the DICOM file into PPM using DCMTK:

```
$ dcmj2pnm ybr16.dcm ybr16.ppm
```

Because my template DICOM file was declared with 16bits allocated bit, but only 12bits stored dcmj2pnm would strip off the high bits of anything above 12bit max value, which would eventually turn into a greenish background.

So in summary: the equations are correct, my test was not.

Comment: I tried your code, and I get the same results (as 16bit YCC), if you want 8-bit YCC just shift the result

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi You can't just shift Cb and Cr, because there is an offset.

Comment: @Rotem: are you sure? the offset is 128 on the higher byte, so.. as expected.

Comment: Just to note: primary color definition changed between 601 and 709 (and YCC often is just 709 or better), and there are two definition: full range (less common, but it seems your method), and restricted range (the default), so when comparing values with other programs, you should check that you are using the same definitions (colour space and range).

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi what do you mean "on the higher byte"? From mathematical point of view, there is no "higher byte", there are just values...

Comment: @Rotem: no, but 16bit and 8bit are computer representation, and "shift" has meaning only on computer integer representation. The formula use floating point numbers, but by using "8-bit" or "16-bit", I interpret them to be put into integers (and so used on normal image compression algorithms). My shift is just on such result. Anyway if you want more mathematics, dividing by 256 has the same results (as in your answer). I do not understand your initial commentary.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi in my initial commentary, I meant you can't do the conversion like this: `Cb16 = Cb8*256`, The correct conversion is: `Cb16 = (Cb8 - 128)*256 + 32768`. **But I was wrong...** (the result is the same).

Comment: @malat, can you please post how did your reach the conclusion that the equations are not correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 16 bits conversion is **correct**.

- For accurate comparison, I removed the `round` - keeping all values in type `double` (just for testing purposes).
- The most important, and confusing thing when comparing Cb,Cr in 8bits and 16bits is the **offset**:
  You need to subtract the offset before scaling (or dividing by `256`):

Assume you have `Cb8` and `Cb16`, and you want to check that the ratio is `256`,
First thing you need to do is subtract `128` from `Cb8`, and subtract `32768` from `Cb16`.
The subtraction operation is like centering the values around zero.

Example:

```
Pb8 = Cb8 - 128
Pb16 = Cb16 - 32768
```

Now you can compare the ratio between `Pb8` and `Pb16`:

```
Pb16 == Pb8*256
```

I used to following MATLAB code (easier than C):

```
R = 50;G = 100;B = 150; %Initialize RGB to arbitrary values.

%8 bits conversion
Y  = min(max( 0, (   0.299 * R + 0.587 * G + 0.114 * B)), 255 );
Cb = min(max( 0, (( -0.299 * R - 0.587 * G + 0.886 * B)/1.772 + 128 )), 255 );
Cr = min(max( 0, ((  0.701 * R - 0.587 * G - 0.114 * B)/1.402 + 128 )), 255 );

%Convert RGB to 16 bits.
scale = 256; %Assume conversion from 8 to 16 bits is scale by 256 (not scale by 65535/255).
R = R*scale;
G = G*scale;
B = B*scale;

%16 bits conversion
Y2  = min(max( 0, (   0.299 * R + 0.587 * G + 0.114 * B)), 65535 );
Cb2 = min(max( 0, (( -0.299 * R - 0.587 * G + 0.886 * B)/1.772 + 32768 )), 65535 );
Cr2 = min(max( 0, ((  0.701 * R - 0.587 * G - 0.114 * B)/1.402 + 32768 )), 65535 );

Ydiff = Y*scale - Y2
Cb_diff = (Cb - 128)*scale - (Cb2 - 32768)
Cr_diff = (Cr - 128)*scale - (Cr2 - 32768)
```

Result:

```
Ydiff = 0
Cb_diff = 0
Cr_diff = 0
```

---

I suppose the following equations applies `Cr` and `Cb` without the offset (what I named `Pb` and `Pr`).

```
E'Cr = ( 0.701 * E'R - 0.587 * E'G - 0.114 * E'B) / 1.402
E'Cb = (-0.299 * E'R - 0.587 * E'G + 0.886 * E'B) / 1.772
```

For 8 bits:

```
Cr = E'Cr + 128
Cb = E'Cb + 128
```

For 16 bits:

```
Cr = E'Cr + 32768
Cb = E'Cb + 32768
```